# Broadcast Receiver class not triggered when app is launched

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

Please I need help. I have 4 BroadcastReceivers: `SimCardStateReceiver`, `AutoTimeReceiver`, `AutoTimeZoneReceiver`, and `TimeZoneReceiver`.
At the moment, only the `SimCardStateReceiver` is triggered. All the others are not triggered (I debugged my code and that was how I noticed that the other Receivers were not triggered aside from the logs that I added in each BroadcastReceiver). Please what am I doing wrong? I have shared all the `BroadcastReceiver`

```
class TimeZoneReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED) {
           isWestAfricaTimeZoneSet(context)
        }
    }

    private fun isWestAfricaTimeZoneSet(context: Context) {
        val baseActivity = context as? BaseActivity
        val viewModel = baseActivity?.simCardViewModel

        val desiredTimeZone = "West Africa Standard Time"
        val currentTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault().displayName
        val compareTimeZone = currentTimeZone.equals(desiredTimeZone, ignoreCase = true)

        if(viewModel?.zoneCheck == true){
            if(compareTimeZone) {
                viewModel.setShowStringDialog("Please Ensure TimeZone is set to West Africa Standard Time.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

:::

```
 class AutoTimeReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
       // logEText("AUTOTIME_RECEIVER", intent.action.toString())
        if (intent.action == "com.mypackageName.ACTION_AUTO_TIME_CHANGED") {
           isAutoTimeEnabled(context)
        }
    }

    private fun isAutoTimeEnabled(context: Context) {
        val baseActivity = context as? BaseActivity
        val viewModel = baseActivity?.simCardViewModel
        val isAutoTimeEnabled = Settings.Global.getInt(context.contentResolver, Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME) == 1

        if(viewModel?.timeCheck == true){
            if(!isAutoTimeEnabled)
                viewModel.setShowStringDialog(context.getString(R.string.time_setup))
        }
    }
}
```

::::

```
 class AutoTimeZoneReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (intent.action == "com.mypackageName.ACTION_AUTO_TIME_ZONE_CHANGED") {
           isAutoTimeZoneEnabled(context)
        }
    }

    private fun isAutoTimeZoneEnabled(context: Context) {
        val baseActivity = context as? BaseActivity
        val viewModel = baseActivity?.simCardViewModel
        val isAutoTimeZone = Settings.Global.getInt(context.contentResolver, Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME_ZONE) == 1

        if(viewModel?.timeZoneCheck == true){
            if(!isAutoTimeZone) {
                viewModel.setShowStringDialog(context.getString(R.string.time_zone_setup))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a BaseActivity class that is extended by all activities in my project and this is how I register all my Broadcasters

```
 open class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        val prefStore: PrefStore by inject()
        val simCardViewModel: SimCardViewModel by viewModel()
    
        private var progDialog: Dialog? = null
        private val intentSim = IntentFilter("android.intent.action.SIM_STATE_CHANGED")
        val intentFilterAutoTime = IntentFilter("com.mypackageName.ACTION_AUTO_TIME_CHANGED")
        val intentFilterAutoTimeZone = IntentFilter("com.mypackageName.ACTION_AUTO_TIME_ZONE_CHANGED")
        val intentFilterTimeZone = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED)
    
        private val simCardStateReceiver = SimCardStateReceiver()
        private val autoTimeReceiver = AutoTimeReceiver()
        private val autoTimeZoneReceiver = AutoTimeZoneReceiver()
        private val timeZoneReceiver = TimeZoneReceiver()
    
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            val crashlytics = FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance()
            crashlytics.setUserId(prefStore.uuid)
            crashlytics.didCrashOnPreviousExecution()
            crashlytics.log(this.javaClass.simpleName)
        }
    
        private fun observer() {
            simCardViewModel.showStringDialog.observe(this) { message ->
                if (progDialog != null && progDialog!!.isShowing) {
                    progDialog?.dismiss()
                }
                if (message.contains("restart device")) {
                    setupDialog(false, message)
                } else {
                    setupDialog(true, message)
                }
               
            }
    
        }
    
        override fun onStart() {
            super.onStart()
            observer()
        }
        private fun registerReceivers() {
            registerReceiver(simCardStateReceiver, intentSim)
            registerReceiver(autoTimeReceiver, intentFilterAutoTime)
            registerReceiver(autoTimeZoneReceiver, intentFilterAutoTimeZone)
            registerReceiver(timeZoneReceiver, intentFilterTimeZone)
        }
    
        private fun unregisterReceivers() {
            unregisterReceiver(simCardStateReceiver)
            unregisterReceiver(autoTimeReceiver)
            unregisterReceiver(autoTimeZoneReceiver)
            unregisterReceiver(timeZoneReceiver)
        }
    
        override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            registerReceivers()
        }
    
    
        override fun onPause() {
            try {
                unregisterReceivers()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                logEText("BROADCASTER->PAUSE", e.message.toString())
            }
            super.onPause()
        }
    
        private fun setupDialog(isTimeSetup: Boolean = true, titleString: String) {
            progDialog = Dialog(this)
            progDialog?.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
            progDialog?.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_setup_screen)
            progDialog?.setCancelable(false)
            val title = progDialog?.findViewById(R.id.title) as TextView
            val settingButton = progDialog?.findViewById(R.id.return_btn) as Button
    
            if (!isTimeSetup) {
                settingButton.visibility = View.GONE
                title.text = titleString
            }
            settingButton.setOnClickListener {
                progDialog?.dismiss()
                startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_DATE_SETTINGS))
              
            }
            progDialog?.show()
        }
    }
```

Please can anyone help me look through my code and tell me why only the `SimCardStateReceiver` is showing its logs while the other 3 BroadcastReceivers are not responding?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to specifically call sendBroadcast for this to work:

```
Intent().also { intent ->
     intent.setAction("com.example.broadcast.MY_NOTIFICATION")
     intent.putExtra("data", "Nothing to see here, move along.")
     sendBroadcast(intent)
}
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts